# Using a void function to update an array but that array is null

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

So I made a void function that should put some values in an array . I call the function , then I call the array variable and it crashes saying that its null. I am also using firebase to get all the values .

This is the Function :

```
    private void findRestaurantKey()
{
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference("x");
    mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                int i = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    allRestNames[i] = d.getKey();
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

And here is how i try to call it :

```
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.food_activity);
    this.findRestaurantKey();
    Log.d("ARRAY" , allRestNames.toString());
  }
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? Where do you declare and initialize the `allRestNames` array?

Comment: Error : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cosnila.orderme/com.cosnila.orderme.Food}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: String[] allRestNames this is how i declared it

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger i am using the findRestaurantKey() , after that i try to call allRestNames array , the array is null . Simple as that

Comment: the array is not being initialized, that is, `allRestNames` is `null`, simple as that

Comment: (just be aware that arrays are just objects, not primitive - you definitively need something like `new String[size]` - otherwise, as any field, it will just get the default value ((`null` for objects)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your array.

```java
List<String> allRestNames = new ArrayList();
```

But if you run the code as you have it, you would not `Log` anything

This is what is called a 'race condition', you are running asynchronous code expecting the result to be there as soon as you call it.

When making a request to an API like you are doing using the Firebase service it takes time.

So what you should do if you wanna Log the results is do it in the callback:

```java
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.food_activity);
    findRestaurantKey();
}


private void findRestaurantKey() {
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference("x");
    mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    allRestNames.add(d.getKey());
                }

                // HERE is when the data is available from the Firebase service
                Log.d("ARRAY" , allRestNames.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What you say is true and it just pushes the NPE to a different line in the code. Now `allRestNames[i]` will throw an NPE because the array still isn't initialized.

Comment: Yes, I had it in the clipboard (editing answers forgot to paste the changes). Thanks for the comment :).

Comment: Seems like my dataSnapshot doesn't exist , it won't do the operations inside that if(){..}

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your array somewhere:

```
allRestNames = new String[5000];
```

Use whatever number is appropriate instead of `5000`. If you don't know what size to make the array to begin with, you should use an `ArrayList` instead of an array.

Also, `findRestaurantKey()` creates a listener for your Firebase database. When this method returns, the data is not yet available because the listener has not yet been called. So even if you solve the current error, you will not get any meaningful data from calling `allRestNames.toString()` in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Exactly this, the question had no answers at the time. Please read the explanations in detail as this is something you'll have to deal with whenever you work with remote services.